# How do I pivot with first and 2nd level aggregation at same table

Tags: python, pandas

How do I pivot with first and 2nd level aggregation at same table, that is Category and Sub Category

Here's my data

```
Name       Category   Sub-Category   sum
yuew       Food       Snack          100
dhjs       Food       Snack          50
jdsd       Food       Drink          60
kjkd       Food       Drink          60
sjdbk      Food       Snack          70
ndkbjd     Clothes    Shirt          80
ndcb       Clothes    Trousers       80
dbkjd      Clothes    Shirt          90
```

I try to code

```
table_pivot = table.pivot_table(values='sum',index=['Category','Sub-Category'],aggfunc=np.sum)
```

Here's the Result, result only specific on sum of every Sub-Category

```
Category                    Sub Category      Sum
Food                        Snack             220
                            Drink             120
Clothes                     Shirt             170
                            Trousers           80
```

What I need is result that not only specific on sum of every Sub-Category but also in Category level

```
Category                    Sub Category      Sum
Food                                          340
                            Snack             220
                            Drink             120
Clothes                                       250 
                            Shirt             170
                            Trousers           80
```

How suppose I do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sum` per first level first, then create `MultiIndex`, [`append`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) to original  and last [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
df = table_pivot.sum(level=0)
df = df.set_index([df.index.values, [''] * len(df)])
print (df)
                       sum
Category Sub-Category     
Clothes                250
Food                   340

df = table_pivot.append(df).sort_index()
print (df)
                       sum
Category Sub-Category     
Clothes                250
         Shirt         170
         Trousers       80
Food                   340
         Drink         120
         Snack         220
```